# Widgets in a ListView losing state while scrolling Flutter

Tags: listview, widget, flutter

I'm getting a JSON from web (world cup matches) and building a ListView with it.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return new Material(
  child: _isLoading
      ? new Center(child: new CircularProgressIndicator())
      : new ListView.builder(
          itemCount: matches != null ? matches["jogos"].length : 0,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            GameBetCard actualGameBetCard = new GameBet(
              homeTeamName: matches["jogos"][index]["m_clube"],
              awayTeamName: matches["jogos"][index]["v_clube"],
              homeTeamId: matches["jogos"][index]["id_clubem"],
              awayTeamId: matches["jogos"][index]["id_clubev"],
              date: matches["jogos"][index]["data"] +
                  " - " +
                  matches["jogos"][index]["hora"],
              stage: Stage.groups,
              groupName: matches["jogos"][index]["nome_grupo"],
              scoreHomeBet: "",
              scoreAwayBet: "",
              scoreHome: matches["jogos"][index]["placarm_tn"],
              scoreAway: matches["jogos"][index]["placarv_tn"],
            ).gameBetCard;
            _addGameBetToList(actualGameBetCard);
            return actualGameBetCard;
          },
        ),
);}
```

I have 2 TextFormFields in GameBetCard, which when i insert something in it, scroll down and scroll up again the card is initiated again withou my data in the TextFormField. Other thing, i have a button where when clicked it inserts to firebase database and then it's completed i change the icon for a Check icon but in the same case of TextFormField it restarts when it gets out of the "screen range"

ps: I was debuggin and saw that the ListView render just the itens that will show up in the screen. When it gets out, it is disposed. When it returns in, it's initiated again by default.

How can i deal with it? i want it to save the state of my Widget.

[image]

Comment: Give your `ListView` a `PageStorageKey`

Comment: Hmmmm i will search about it!

Answer (score 0):

Your TextFormField need to have their own TextEditingController.

These TextEditingController should be at the top Widget (the one that contains the ListView). If you don't do that, the TextEditingController will also be destroyed/recreated when the individual widget is destroyed/recreated.

Create the two TextEditingControllers on top and pass them to your GameBet widget, then set them to the TextFormFields inside.

Also, the top Widget should be a Stateful Widget so the Controllers won't get destroyed when the widget is rebuild. Finally, you should also dispose the controllers.

See this example:

```dart
class MyForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyFormState createState() => _MyFormState();
}

class _MyFormState extends State<MyForm> {
  TextEditingController _controller1, _controller2;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller1 = new TextEditingController();
    _controller2 = new TextEditingController();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _controller1.dispose();
    _controller2.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Material(
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: count,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return GameBet(
            controller1: _controller1,
            controller2: _controller2,
            // rest of fields
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Then, inside your GameBet, remember to set the controllers:

```dart
TextFormField(
  controller: _controller1,
)
```